# mySQL returns wrong Count result

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is sqlFiddle for my database and my count query...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45150/6

If I run a select * query, it returns me one row, however when I run count on the same query, it gives me 2 results...

This is the the query for count, it produces different result for "select *"

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (`user_info`)

JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id`=`user_info`.`user_id`

LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `users`.`id`=`profile`.`user_id`

JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`

WHERE `users`.`is_enabled` =  1
AND `categories`.`cat_id` IN (1, 3, 4) 
AND ( 
 user_info.first_name LIKE '%bob%'  
 OR user_info.last_name LIKE '%bob%' 
 OR profile.title LIKE '%bob%' 
 OR profile.overview LIKE '%bob%'  
 )
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

Comment: select * returns 2 rows for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45150/22

Comment: @cha because you didn't put `group by users.id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned you can have multiple categories associated with a user. Therefore, using COUNT(*) is not possible in your situation. To fix it you can use either of the following options:

Quite simply, use SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `users`.`id`), like in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45150/25):

```
SELECT count(distinct `users`.`id`)
FROM (`user_info`)
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id`=`user_info`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `users`.`id`=`profile`.`user_id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `users`.`is_enabled` =  1
AND `categories`.`cat_id` IN (1, 3, 4) 
AND ( 
 user_info.first_name LIKE '%bob%'  
 OR user_info.last_name LIKE '%bob%' 
 OR profile.title LIKE '%bob%' 
 OR profile.overview LIKE '%bob%'  
 )
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

However, this will only hide the problem. The problem will reappear if you start adding new aggregate functions to your select statement (like SUM(salary), etc.)

The proper solution will be, I guess is to fix the duplication and modify your FROM clause, like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (`user_info`)
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id`=`user_info`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `profile` ON `users`.`id`=`profile`.`user_id`
WHERE `users`.`is_enabled` =  1
AND ( 
 user_info.first_name LIKE '%bob%'  
 OR user_info.last_name LIKE '%bob%' 
 OR profile.title LIKE '%bob%' 
 OR profile.overview LIKE '%bob%'  
 )
AND `users`.`id` IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`cat_id` IN (1, 3, 4) )


GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45150/28)

Answer (score 4):

That happens because you're grouping by the user id.

If you want to run a `select *` then you will have to remove the `group by` clause. That would return the 2 results that the `count(*)` is returning. Those results happen to have the same id so they are grouped into only one result.

**Edit after radical question change:**

In a comment the OP mentioned:

> I want to look for any user with more than one categories (coming from search)

That means you can't just blindly join on the categories table. You have to first check whether the user has more than one category assigned (that matches `cat_id IN (1, 3, 4)`). You can do that this way:

```
SELECT * FROM user_info ui
JOIN `users` u ON u.id = ui.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile p ON u.id = p.user_id
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id FROM categories
  WHERE cat_id IN (1, 3, 4) 
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) c ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.is_enabled = 1 AND ( 
  ui.first_name LIKE '%bob%' OR
  ui.last_name LIKE '%bob%' OR
  p.title LIKE '%bob%' OR
  p.overview LIKE '%bob%'  
)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70407/1).

Comment: but I want to see only one user? Each user has more than one categories selected in categories table... i don't want to repeat them?

for example, search can be for categories id 1, 2, 3 and user 1 has 1, 2, 3 in table, it will show me 3 times user 1, I want to disply him only once???

Comment: I've explained why the `wrong Count result` is not wrong. If you need a particular output then you should add that to the question. Anyway, if you want to only display the user in one row... then what category id will contain that row? I can see in the query you added that the user has cat_id 4 and 1... which one would you choose to display in that row and why?

Comment: Appreciate that.. but you see, in the query I have 

JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
AND `categories`.`cat_id` IN (1, 3, 4) ........ and cat_id is coming from array... which is dublicating the rows because of having more than one categories assigned to each user. I am getting correct results the problem is with count, what can I do to make it right?

Comment: Basically, I want to look for any user with more than one categories (coming from search)... As long as the user has that category assigned, I want to display its record.. Sorry if I am not good in explaining it...

Comment: You said `I want to look for any user with more than one categories (coming from search)`. The `cat_id in (1, 3, 4)` will not give you the results you're looking for. If it only matches `1` it will return it but you said `with more than one categories` so it shouldn't

Comment: Tried this script and it is working perfect, thanks... I used the above answer (using sub-query) it is helping me to modify my query for for fetching more fields from different tables easily... THANKS A LOT.. Didn't know group by doesn't work well with count..

Comment: Welcome. But bear in mind that the cha's answer will return users matching ANY of those three categories. If you need to have them match more than one then you will have to use the `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`